# Transform Http Response to object mule esb

Tags: java, mule, httpresponse

Im doing a sample bookstore. When the user has booked a order, the system send him an email with the dates from the order. The system send the email but it shows the next error:

```
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot apply transformer HttpClientMethodResponseToObject{this=6911a11b, name='HttpClientMethodResponseToPedido', ignoreBadInput=false, returnClass=SimpleDataType{type=org.mule.entities.Pedido, mimeType='text/html'}, sourceTypes=[SimpleDataType{type=org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod, mimeType='*/*'}]} on source payload: class org.mule.transport.http.HttpResponse
at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyAllTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1427)
at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1379)
at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.applyTransformers(DefaultMuleMessage.java:1371)
+ 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

---

My XML is the next:

```
<smtp:gmail-connector name="Gmail" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Gmail" contentType="text/html"   />
<flow name="Email" doc:name="Email">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8088" doc:name="HTTP" path="Email"/>
    <http:static-resource-handler resourceBase="docroot" defaultFile="index.html" doc:name="HTTP Static Resource Handler"/>
</flow>
<flow name="Correo" doc:name="Correo">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8088" path="Facturacion" doc:name="HTTP" transformer-refs="Java"/>
    <component doc:name="Generar Pedido" class="org.mule.components.GenerarPedido"/>
    <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" user="email%40gmail.com" password="pass" connector-ref="Gmail" to="#[payload.email]" from="BookStore S.A." responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP" transformer-refs="Java1" mimeType="text/html"/>
    <http:response-builder status="200" contentType="text/html" doc:name="HTTP Response Builder"/>
    <http:http-response-to-object-transformer returnClass="org.mule.entities.Pedido" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/html" doc:name="HTTP Response to Object"/>
</flow>
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your payload is not a HTTP response, so you cannot use the http-response-to-object-transformer. This is used after calling an http:outbound-endpoint which returns a 'HTTP response'.

Comment: This is correct, I reckon what the OP want is to use `set-payload` instead, to set the body of the HTTP response.

Comment: Im doing what you say but i dont have the expected result. are there any tutorial or link about this?